# How to rewrite a complex comparative sentence into a single sentence.

Tags: comparison

> As the temperature is higher, the amount of food that my dog eats is
>   lesser.

I am trying to rewrite the above sentence into a single sentence.  My draft is as follows:

> The amount of food that my dog eats decreases with an increase in the
>   temperature.

Could you advise me on my draft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tere is nothing wrong with your sentence

> The amount of food that my dog eats decreases with an increase in the temperature.

You could make the sentence more *active* by saying

> As the temperature rises, my dog eats less.
>   My dog eats less as the temperature rises.

or if you wanted to sound scientific

> My dog's appetite is inversely correlated with the temperature.

this assumes that as the temperature falls, your dog will eat more.